# How to repair this error of executing?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-image, sdl-mixer

Every time I compile my simple SDL1.2 code it's compiled successfully
but when I try to run it via terminal (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> in Ubuntu):

```
./game
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I get this error. Can you help please? This is the code:

```
#include<SDL/SDL.h>

int main(int argc,char args)    
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);    
    SDL_Surface* screen;        
    screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_HWSURFACE);
    SDL_Flip(screen) ![problem running the program][1];
    SDL_Delay(5000);    
    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);    
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger. Moreover; C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: You're not checking whether `SDL_SetVideoMode` was successful.

Comment: Perhaps you need to allocate something to `*screen`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `SDL_SetVideoMode` will return a pointer to a `SDL_Surface`.

Comment: I take it `![problem running the program][1]` isn't really in there?

Comment: Side-note: You should *not* call `SDL_FreeSurface(screen);`. `SDL_Quit();` does that for you for that particular surface (and only for that one). See "Return Value" section: http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html

Answer (score 1):

`SDL_SetVideoMode` returns `NULL` on error which you do not check for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running this via a terminal, I suspect you may have forgotten to tell Xorg to allow running from it. In fact, if this is really the problem it'll prevent *any* program from running when started that way.

To fix the problem, enter this into the terminal (this only needs to be done once per session):

```
xhost +
```

You should get a message that it was successful. I cannot recall the exact message, but it is something like this:

```
Clients are now allowed to connect from any host.
```

What was happening (assuming that I was correct regarding `xhost`) was that the `SDL_SetVideoMode()` call was failing and returning `NULL`, because Xorg rejected the connection. Since you're not checking for that, `SDL_Flip()` ended dereferencing a `NULL` pointer --- hence the segfault.

---

**SIDE-NOTE:** There is an error in your code, however --- namely, you should *not* call `SDL_FreeSurface(screen);`; that particular surface is special, and is freed by `SDL_Quit();` automatically. Source (see "Return Value" section): http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html

Answer (score 0):

Run it under valgrind. Or GDB. Or some other debugger of your choice.

You should probably be *successfully* allocating memory for screen.

Comment: `SDL_SetVideoMode` allocates the memory for you (and you should *NOT* allocate it yourself --- unless you want a memory leak), so your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Calling SDL_SetVideoMode _is_ allocating memory yourself. Which returns NULL in the time honoured tradition of near-fatal memory allocation errors. I'll add the word "successfully" to the answer.

Comment: Well, depends on the perspective; generally, when an API allocates the memory behind your back, it's usually said that you are *not* allocating it yourself (doing it yourself would mean having it on the stack *or* using `malloc` and then passing a pointer). Your original answer implied you meant this. At any rate, this does not resolve his core problem --- namely, that the window creation is failing.

Comment: To add to the above: If you say `SDL_SetVideoMode` is allocating memory by yourself, then there's no point in saying that. Otherwise, *EVERYTHING* is allocating it yourself (since, when you go back up the stack, you'll *eventually* hit your own code; even if you're currently somewhere deep within the kernel because of a system call).

Answer (score 0):

Check if [`SDL_SetVideoMode()`](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html) failed!

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
if (screen == NULL) /* error  */;
```

Comment: if (screen == NULL) /* error  */;
printf("erreur") ;
when i re-run the program it works fine wait for 5 seconds then the screen show me erreur then there is an error loading the screen

Comment: `if (screen == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "erreur"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`